# In typescript, why is `[boolean, string?]` different from `[boolean, string] | [boolean]`?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, a tuple of type `[boolean, string?]` cannot be used for an interface or type expecting `[boolean, string] | [boolean]`. My understanding is typescript considers it different because in the second case you're either getting `[boolean, string]` or `[boolean]` - not a more generic tuple type supporting both. To that I say: sure, but the compiler still sees it as `[boolean, string] | [boolean]` (i.e. it could be either type at runtime), so why not have these types be considered the same? Was it an arbitrary decision not to simplify types in this way, or is there a defect that would occur if this was done?

Comment: Note that you keep saying `[boolean, string] | [string]` instead of `[boolean, string] | [boolean]`; the former is trivially different from `[boolean, string?]` while the latter difference has more to do with unions-of-objects and objects-of-unions not being treated identically in TypeScript for better or worse.

Comment: I edited it so that it makes sense.

Comment: If the question is "why are these not considered the same" (and we forget `undefined`) I think the canonical answer must be as in [microsoft/TypeScript#14865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14865); prohibitively expensive to check all unions everywhere and normalize them in such a way, for questionable benefit.  There's also a little bit of assignment differences, since you should be able to write `foo[1] = "hello"` for `[boolean, string?]` but not for `[boolean, string] | [boolean]`.  But TS has never been incredibly sound about property writes, so it's secondary.

Comment: All right I'm going to write up an answer here when I get a chance

Answer (score 3):

These types are different:

```
// OK
const p1: [boolean, string?] = [true, undefined];
// Error
const p2: [boolean, string] | [boolean] = [true, undefined];
```

Comment: It would be interesting to say why these are still different in the face of [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes).  I'd say this is really about the difference between single objects with union-typed properties and unions of non-union typed properties, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLRxKw).  Am I off base here?

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14865 to me

Answer (score 0):

As @RyanCavanaugh said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635611/2887218), when [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) is enabled and [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) is not, then you can assign `undefined` to any [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), including [optional tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types).  Whereas a missing/undeclared property is not necessarily going to accept `undefined`, so there is trivially a difference between `[boolean, string?]` and `[boolean, string] | [boolean]` if you assign a value of `undefined` to the second element.

Of course, if you enable `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` then one may not assign `undefined` to all optional properties, and there's much less of a difference:

```
// --exactOptionalPropertyTypes enabled

const p1: [boolean, string?] = [true, undefined]; // error!
// ---------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

const p2: [boolean, string] | [boolean] = [true, undefined]; // error!
// -> ~~
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

So I think the spirit of this question has not been addressed by the other answer.  From here on out, let's imagine that you have `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` enabled or that you change the `[boolean]` in your question to something like `[boolean, never?]`, so that both types take the same set of values.

---

It's a reasonable intuition to think of a type as corresponding exactly to the set of values that inhabit it; so one can consider `string` as being "equivalent" to the infinite union of all string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), for example.  If JavaScript were a purely functional language with no side effects or mutation, then maybe these equivalences would be exact.  But things get complicated when you consider mutations and assignments, and how TypeScript treats them.

Let's consider the types: `{a: boolean}` versus `{a: true} | {a: false}`.  The first type is a single object type whose `a` property is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type that can be either `true` or `false`.  That means you are allowed to do this:

```
let x: { a: boolean } = { a: true };
x.a = false;
```

Meanwhile, a value of type `{a: true}` must always have a `true` value as its `a` property, and a value of type `{a: false}` must always have `false`.  The union of these two object types corresponds to something which is either the first type (something whose `a` property is always `true`) or the second type (something whose `a` property is always `false`).  Neither of these types allows you to reassign the `a` property to something other than what it is, and so it should not necessarily be expected that the union of these types should suddenly allow such reassignment.

So you are allowed to assign `{a: true}` or `{a: false}` to a variable of that union type:

```
let y: { a: true } | { a: false } = { a: true };
```

But it is not obvious that you would be allowed to reassign the `a` property.  And in fact, TypeScript does complain about this:

```
y.a = false; // error!
```

In TypeScript, variables of union types like `y` undergo [control flow narrowing upon assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments); so when you write `let y: {a: true} | {a: false} = {a: true}`, the compiler narrows the apparent type of `y` to just `{a: true}`.  You can reassign all of `y`:

```
y = { a: false }; // okay
```

but you can't mutate the contents of `y` so that it changes the narrowed type.   And the same thing happens with the tuples in your question:

```
const p3: [boolean, string?] = [true];
const p3SecondEl = p3[1]; // okay

const p4: [boolean, string] | [boolean] = [true];
const p4SecondEl = p4[1]; // error!
```

Did TypeScript *have* to be this way?  No, of course the language designers could have decided that two types with the same set of inhabitants were the same type.  But then the question would be: how would the compiler enforce such an equivalence?

---

For that, let's look at [microsoft/TypeScript#14865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14865), a suggestion that unions in object properties should be normalized so that, for example, `{a: true} | {a: false}` should be collapsed to `{a: boolean}` (or maybe vice versa).  This would aid in the sort of type compatibility check you want to see.

Unfortunately, as [the lead architect for the language @AndersHejlsberg said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14865#issuecomment-302092932):

> This sort of unification is only possible for a small subset of types. [...] It's not clear to me it is worth the extra work to attempt to unify the types as it would fail in almost all cases but add cost in every case.

Let's say the compiler was presented with type `{x: A, y: B, z: C}` where `A` is a union of n<sub>A</sub> members, `B` is a union of n<sub>B</sub> members, and `C` is a union of n<sub>C</sub> members.  Then in order to normalize that type, you would end up with a union of n<sub>A</sub>×n<sub>B</sub>×n<sub>C</sub> members.  You end up exploding the number of members of unions by converting everything to its [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  This gets even worse when these unions are themselves nested in subproperties.  Unions become very expensive.

And most of the time, such work is pointless, because most of the time, two types written differently like this are not equivalent in terms of allowed values.  So the heuristic that no two differently-written union types are identical is convenient, if disappointing.

---

That's not the *whole* story; people complained about this enough that there was a change made in TypeScript 3.5 to [perform some more complex union type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) in the specific case where the unions are [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and the union-typed properties are discriminant types, and only if there are less than about 25 members total when taking the cartesian product (so it bails out pretty quickly); see [microsoft/TypeScript#30779](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779) for the issues involved.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEFpwUwDwQwMYBcDyAHJBLA9gOzgDYAKATtmlCUgJ4Aq1FAzqFPgEYFQAmAUDwnkZJQaAIwAuUAG022bJzi4ANKCElMuAOYB+ALqgAvNKQkArlBWncXKADMN3XQG5QIFiTIkAhDzeR-AYFBwUEAfKAAflHR0b5g9BSgAORWNva43EmgmMy42MJwjIyYmuycoEjYFQxQyWoamkl8ArhCIgBMkjJyCsqqJg36AD7SsvJQivpGUibmltZ2DlzOrmCUnj5+4VFxoAm1KQvpmdm5+aCFxaVwHLWV1YlJ9VpNfG5IABZQ1BcktUKYAgECp-OBIbigLiYWy2SisJAEagqT7YUyaD4qLjmCpVMycZg3VHCKw4XAiMhoOCaMGk8TNQTCNAAZi6Y16KmeOimxjMUGc-AZIiZAGUoC0uABRYFGZlSUQrNzYADWcCR-XUWlAI1SiwyvAFrUZABZWT0Jn1OcNRmbJoYeeZ+S02mgjaLxVK7S65Qq1h5sN49qY0OUaI9uuNJllsLZQJwtJ9kqIsh9CqA8ixOABbeEXYQaGwwROvHicYQwSQAbwukjZ5tAAF87VW4JJZrV604eDAAHRwO22QiMKAuRUq6hdpvV0ADghDhsjsDK1V8UugaiVqdthta0DNyQzueNox7kHYjs8ai9-uD4erdwbC+TlvTm-zu9L6hAA)